# Create shortcut for creating new folder in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there any way to set a shortcut (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>) for creating a new folder in windows 7?

This is obviously instead of right clicking and pressing create new folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This shortcut is already in Windows 7.

You need to press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

This creates a new folder named `New Folder` and that name is highlighted so you can edit the name as soon as you press the shortcut, just like you would when using the context menu